I am using docker-slim base image. Installed very minimal dependencies, and the final image file goes >1GB
I am very new to Docker but enjoying the study. Recently I have tried to build an image for a simple ML app that I had build earlier. I have used python:3.11-slim base image and installed a few dependencies. After the final build, the image size turned out to be 1.13 GB. How is this happening?
Following is my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim

EXPOSE 8080

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN  pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk del .build-deps

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.port=8080"]

=================================================================
Following is my requirements.txt:
joblib==1.4.2
numpy==1.26.4
scikit-learn==1.5.0
scipy==1.13.1
streamlit==1.35.0
xgboost==2.1.0


I think a couple of those packages are just that big.  If you install the same application into a non-Docker virtual environment, is the size any different?

Yes, the environment size roughly goes to the same size.

In general, dependencies that you install usually pull further dependencies along them.
In your example, XGBoost and scikit-learn are heavy packages that most likely pulled further binary files while installing.
I ran your Dockerfile and at first glance noticed this layer of the build:

It appears to be the main source of your large image.
Looking a bit closer, these are the top 3 largest pip dependencies after building the image:
240M    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xgboost
129M    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow
79M     /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas
[...]

Some of them are Sub-dependencies of your requirements.txt

Okay, thank you for your support.

You can check all the dependencies and its sizes by saving your output to separate buildinfo file:
docker build . --no-cache > build_output.txt 2>&1

Here we can see that only 2 dependencies took ~ 400mb.
#7 44.94 Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu12-2.23.4-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (199.0 MB)
#7 62.85    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 199.0/199.0 MB 11.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#7 19.60 Downloading scipy-1.13.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (38.6 MB)
#7 23.01    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 38.6/38.6 MB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#7 23.85 Downloading xgboost-2.1.0-py3-none-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (153.9 MB)
#7 37.49    ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 153.9/153.9 MB 11.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00


Okay, I will try this. Thank you for the support.
